# How to setup a raspberry pi 3 with two bluetooth connections at the same time?

Tags: bluetooth, raspberry-pi3

Hello my name is Edris,

I am looking to make a connection between a raspberry and 2 arduino's with bluetooth. So the raspberry pi 3 would be the master and the arduino's slaves.

But then I thought mayby is it easier to have two connections at the same time.

So one with the build in bluetooth chip 
and the other
with a usb bluetooth stick.

The bluetooth chips are all BLUE LoW Energy. Also the build in chip in the raspberry pi 3

Looking forward to hear from someone.

Edris

Answer (score 0):

[here are a couple of ways to connect](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=53299&p=409980)

my preference is bluetoothctl. you'll be able to control each dongle by it's ID, given its ID appears when you do `scan on` and a list of IDs prints